# Grid system - Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a site with bootstrap style but i have a doubt about grid system. I have the follow structure:
(Inside the 'form-group' div I need to put a label for my combobox and under it a plus icon and my combobox).

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">

 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label class="form-label">Label</label><br>

  <?php
   echo $this->Html->link('<i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click here" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 18px;" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>',
    '#',
 
    array(
         'data-toggle'=> 'modal',
         'data-target' => '#OpenModal',
         'escape' => false
         )
   );
  ?>

  <select></select>
 </div>

</div>
```

But if I code this way, my form be like:

[image: code representation]

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant. Show your rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: My PHP code is what generate the icon

Comment: I know and it is irrelevant to people who want to help :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase col width col-md-3 to col-md-4 or more so that it could contains  icon and input or you will need to overwrite col-md-3 by removing margin and padding

[image]

this what you want to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label class="form-label">Label</label><br>

            <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click here" style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 18px;" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>




        <select></select>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have changed the column width but independs of it, my icon always stay under all

Comment: which means that you have a problem in rendered html code after running php code